# How To Add A Folder Of Images To IKImageBrowserView

Tags: xcode, nsfilemanager, ikimagebrowserview, imagekit, ikimageview

How do I add a folder of images to be displayed in an IKImageBrowserView?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [IKImageBrowserView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html), there you will find the [**`ImageKitDemo`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ImageKitDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004371). That example shows you how to add photos to the `IKImageBrowserView` using directories